# Pandas parse date and set index- weird behavior

Tags: python, pandas, io, date-parsing

I am experiencing some odd behavior when I try to both parse a date column and set that column as the index while reading from a CSV with pandas.

The csv file has both a throw-away header and a throw-away index column like below (by throw-away I mean I don't want to use them)

```
"","X.m..d..y","fizzBuzz"
"1","2/2/1984",0.02523659
"2","2/3/1984",-0.03692308
"3","2/6/1984",-0.01597444
"4","2/7/1984",-0.006493506
"5","2/8/1984",-0.0130719
```

Now, I can easily read the df and then set the index afterwards with the following snippet

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('stackOverflow.csv',header=0,
                   names=['_throAwayindex','date','value'], usecols=['date','value'],
                  parse_dates=['date'] )
df = df.set_index('date')
df
```

Which perfectly outputs the desired result

```
               value
date                
1984-02-02  0.025237
1984-02-03 -0.036923
1984-02-06 -0.015974
1984-02-07 -0.006494
1984-02-08 -0.013072
```

But when I try to set the index in the `read_csv` call, I get a strange result. This mis-names the index column

```
df = pd.read_csv('stackOverflow.csv',header=0,
                   names=['_throAwayindex','date','value'], usecols=['date','value'],
                  parse_dates=['date'], index_col=0 )
df
                   value
_throAwayindex          
2/2/1984        0.025237
2/3/1984       -0.036923
2/6/1984       -0.015974
2/7/1984       -0.006494
2/8/1984       -0.013072
```

And this does everything wrong:

```
df = pd.read_csv('stackOverflow.csv',header=0,
                   names=['_throAwayindex','date','value'], usecols=['date','value'],
                  parse_dates=['date'], index_col=1 )
df
               date
date               
 0.025237  2/2/1984
-0.036923  2/3/1984
-0.015974  2/6/1984
-0.006494  2/7/1984
-0.013072  2/8/1984
```

I'm interested both in what is happening and also how could achieve the desired result in just the `read_csv` call without the second call to `set_index`.

Comment: The strategy with `index_col=0` works for me (Python 3.5.1, pandas 0.18.1). There was a bug that showed up when using both `parse_dates` and `usecols` that has been fixed in 0.18.1 (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/c6c201e27c7ed57a823ec7261340dfeec1e0226a) Maybe you're running an older version?

Comment: that is it. upgraded and it works fine. Gracias .if you post the answer i can mark it closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strategy with `index_col=0` works for me (Python 3.5.1, pandas 0.18.1). There was a bug that showed up when using both `parse_dates` and `usecols` that has been fixed in 0.18.1 ([commit](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/commit/c6c201e27c7ed57a823ec7261340dfeec1e0226a)). Maybe you're running an older version?